# Social Connected module / Social possibilities for Sitecore 9

Tags: social-connected

I assume that because of big changes in architecture introduced in `Sitecore 9` with `xConnect`, there is still no `Social Connected` module for `Sitecore 9`.

This module could be installed as separate  module for `Sitecore 7`. For `Sitecore 8`, it was integrated.

1)
Do you have any information whether `Social Connected` module will be again available in next `Sitecore 9` update? Like it was with `EXM` in `Sitecore 9 Update 1`.

2)
I saw [Sitecore page](https://www.sitecore.com/products/sitecore-experience-platform/cross-channel-delivery/social) with alternatives like `Slackla` and `Teligent`.
Do you have any experience with them? Are these good alternatives? Do you know about other alternatives?

For now we are using for social interaction `AddThis component` from `SXA` but we are missing really great integration with `Sitecore` which was available with `Social Connected` module like number of likes / retweets and possibility to share from Content Editor.

Comment: Can you clarify which social functions you are looking for? 'Social' is a very broad category. If you specify the functionality you need, it will be easier for somebody to make a recommendation.

Comment: Basically Social Connected module for Sitecore 8 and it's features. I have updated question a bit. @JayS - Will Social Connected module be released for Sitecore 9?

Comment: Telligent is definitely not the same thing. It isn’t for sharing on social networks. It is a platform for building you own Community with user profiles, messaging, Blogs, Forums, Wikis and Media Galleries etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)
There is no official statement from Sitecore whether they will integrate Social Connected module with Sitecore 9 as they did with Sitecore 8. I personally doubt that it will actually happen.

2)
Stackla and Telligent cannot be compared to this Social Connected module as they are used for completely different scenarios and serve different purposes.

3) At the end we end up with mixed solution that I described [in my blog post](http://tothecore.sk/2018/03/29/social-sharing-in-sitecore-9) in more detail.

Here is overview of the solution:

- On FE side we have used [SXA](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator) and its [AddThis](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/the_sxa_renderings_and_rendering_variants#_Social) component together with our [AddThis account](https://www.addthis.com/) where we have placed in the footer possibility to follow our company accounts and widget on the side to share currently visited page

[image] [image]

- More information can be found [here](http://tothecore.sk/2018/03/29/social-sharing-in-sitecore-9).
- On BE side we have done custom solution - We have added buttons to Content Editor to its ribbon on certain templates. Items based on these templates where then shareable on Facebook and LinkedIn. Because of the time constraints, we have made simple integration just by using share urls. We haven't done full integration using Facebook or LinkedIn API's.

[image]

- More information can be found [here](http://tothecore.sk/2018/05/31/adding-custom-social-buttons-to-content-editor-in-sitecore-9).

With this mixed approach we gave ability to share pages/items to visitors of the site on their walls and activities and also for content editors to share pages/items on company Facebook/LinkedIn pages

Comment: Hello @Peter Procházka , i was trying to add social share to my site, however i'm facing a problem. In Facebook and linked-in i was only able to share the current page url, but i also need to share more details such as description, title and image. I am using fb and linked-in APIs which only allow sharing the url. Would you please tell me if there is a way to share more details?

Comment: Hi @AmiraElEwady. I would suggest to create a separate question for your problem and link this question/answer there. Your question is not for comment format to another question.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Release Notes of Sitecore Experience Platform 9.0 Initial Release (rev.171002):
"**The Social Connected application is not included in Sitecore 9.0. Information about future availability will be confirmed at a later date.**"

For more details please take a look at the mentioned Release Notes: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/90/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2090%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes

[image]

Answer (score 2):

SocialConnect module launched,
"Build your network quick and easy"
https://www.addact.in/addact-socialconnect

Comment: For anyone who wants to look into SocialConnect by Addact – as a valid alternative to the deprecated Social Connected IMHO – check out this blog post on the module: https://sitecore.namics.com/2019/04/29/sitecore9-socialmedia-integration-socialconnected-module/

We successfully tested it on a Sitecore 9.0 and Sitecore 9.1 Habitat solution.

Answer (score 0):

Stackla Dashboard allows you to create widgets and customise them as you wish, and then generates a code that you can embed into your website page. You can be more clever when embedding Stackla widgets into Sitecore and specify dynamic parameters based on how you want to change Stackla settings and your variety of pages where you will place your module on. I can offer you my implementation of Stackla widgets in Sitecore released on GitHub [here](https://github.com/kate-orlova/stackla-widgets-in-sitecore). Please check, it can be helpful for you.